# Is there an AE script api can take a part of an audio and video layer file and place it at the specified inpoint and outpoint？

Tags: jsx, after-effects

Scene description:  I want to intercept a part of an audio and video layer file and place it at the specified inpoint outpoint;

expected outcome: 
The expected result is shown below，
[First paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w8ah.png)
[Second paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6b06.png)

get expected by using AE software and the command is command + shift + d:

[use ae soft ware can get what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsU6y.png)

Final question: 
  how to get the expected result by using ae script。 How to achieve the target by call some ae script api ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review and edit your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hey markfork, welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like your question is not directly reated to programming, but rather a user's question looking for a plug-in or something similar. Please note that these questions are off-topic on SO. You might consider asking on https://video.stackexchange.com

In case you have attempted writing some code to produce the effects you desire, please add the code to your question so we can help you out. Thanks!